# Deleting records based on run date in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am able to delete the data in a table for a particular run date and I am not able to delete the data for another run date.

Ex: I am able to delete data on `22-nov-2017` run date but not able to delete for `21-nov-2017`

here is the query i am using

```
DELETE FROM country WHERE trunc(RUN_DATE) = '21-NOV-17'
```

Comment: Your query is fine for Oracle, although I would use the syntax for the constant as `DATE '2017-11-21'`.

Comment: What is the symptom that you are not able to do that? Is there any error message ?

Comment: same is working for '22-NOV-17' @GordonLinoff

Comment: @GordonLinoff  - the query is not fine for Oracle; it relies on NLS_DATE_FORMAT being 'dd-MON-rr'. It might very well be 'rr-MON-dd'. The query with a string on the right side of = is wrong for all database products.

Comment: No it's just executing until i stop it manualy @krokodilko

Comment: @john . . . Despite decades of Oracle tradition, mathguy is right.  You really should be using `date` or `to_date()` as explained in the documentation:  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ.

Comment: @john - why are you stopping it manually? It seems what you are saying is that the query IS executing; rather, it may take too long? That may happen either because the table (or part of it) happens to be locked, and you are waiting your turn; or because you have much more data to delete for 21 NOV vs. 22 NOV. In any case, do write the dates correctly. And if performance is an issue, don't use TRUNC on RUN_DATE; instead write it as `RUN_DATE >= date '2017-11-21' and RUN_DATE < date '2017-11-22'`.

Comment: I think we're going to need to see an EXPLAIN PLAN for both variations of the query (the one that completes and the one that does not). Perhaps your table has a billion records for 21 nov, but 0 for 22 nov

Comment: Get a count to see how many records are present for both dates. And check some other dates. It seems like there are too many records for that specific date and it might take some time to delete them. Or as mathguy said, it might be locked for something so just give it time till you get some message back. You can check the locks on a table. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56615/how-to-determine-if-an-oracle-table-is-locked-or-not

Answer (score 2):

I think you are getting a date format error.

Maybe this would work better:

```
DELETE FROM country WHERE trunc(RUN_DATE) = To_date('21-NOV-17','DD-MON-YY')
```